# Почему то не работает подсветка кода в vs code (Golang)

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

[image: Все go tools я поставил, так же сам код компилируется]

По какой то причине нет подсветки синтаксиса в vs code, сам го установлен и настроен, скачано расширение и установлены все go install tools

Comment: В смысле нету подсветки, у вас на скрине всё подсвечивается.

Comment: Println нет, да и так же с другими

Comment: Какая у вас тема? Нажмите Ctrl-K Ctrl-T и выберите другую тему. Что изменится? И отключите Screen Reader Optimized

Comment: Спасибо большое, и вправду проблема была в теме, очень странно что стандартная тема не подсвечивает синтаксис =/